# How to perform if statements on associated has_many records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a model Project, which has many Tasks. Each Task has a :status field, which is an integer as follows

```
1=Normal
2=Urgent
```

In the Project show view, I want to display a text alert if any of the associated tasks are flagged as urgent.

If the status field was within the Project model, I would do something like this:

```
<% if Project.status == 2 %>
   <div class="alert">URGENT TASKS!</div>
<% end %>
```

How can I set up a similar if statement, that will cycle through all associated Tasks, and return true if at least one task is marked as urgent?

I'm not sure what terms I should be searching on for this sort of functionality. Or maybe I'm not looking at the problem the right way. I'd be grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method in Project will do it:

```
def urgent?
  tasks.detect{|t| t.status==2}
end
```

Then you can do, if you have `@project` set to the project you're looking at:

```
<% if @project.urgent? %>
  ...whatever ...
<% end %>
```

---

This next bit was added in answer to your comment. This method in Project will return the highest priority set (lowest number in your example) for any task in a particular project:

```
def highest_priority
  tasks.map{|t| t.status}.min
end
```

You can then switch between them in your view:

```
<% case @project.highest_priority
   when 1 %>
     ...priority 1 stuff...
<% when 2 %>
     ...priority 2 stuff...
<% when 3 %>
     ...and so on...
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks kevtufc, that's a nice solution. How would I extend this to cover more options. For example with a greater number of statuses, e.g. `1=high, 2=med, 3=low, 4=very low...etc`, and I want to display a message if there is a high status, if not then I want to display a message if there is a medium status, if not... Would I need to create a separate method for each condition - `def high?, def med?, def low?` - or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to check if a project has some urgent task to be completed. If thats the case I think the best way to achieve that would be to create new method in the Project model, something like this:

```
def has_urgent_task?
  tasks.map(&:status).include?(Task::URGENT) 
end
```

Assuming you have defined your statuses as constants in your Task model, if not just replace Task::URGENT for 2.

So in your view you only need to do this:

```
<% if @project.has_urgent_task? %>
  <div class="alert">URGENT TASKS!</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks cicloon, nice solution. I went with kevtufc's answer because it seems an elegant solution. Yours also worked however :). Thanks for the help